# How to divide a batch into multiple batches to set documents in Firestore from Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an application on Android and Firestore. When I try to upload the information to Firestore using a **batch**, I receive the following message:

> com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException:
>   INVALID_ARGUMENT: maximum 500 writes allowed per request

I understand that this is a standard limitation for everyone (see [Usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions)), but how can the batch be divided into multiple batches to avoid this problem?

```
WriteBatch batch = mFirestore.batch();

batch.set(personRef, personData); // This is done 1 time
batch.set(productRef, myProduct, SetOptions.merge()); // This is done multiple times
batch.set(inventoryRef, inventoryData); // This is done multiple times
batch.set(clientRef, clientData); // This is done multiple times

batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Batch successfully completed!");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error batch: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

I have searched for information about it, but, I only find solutions for Web using `async / task`, nothing that helps for Android.

I have tried this, but, without luck:

```
WriteBatch batch = mFirestore.batch(); 
int operationCounter = 0;

// This is just 1 time
DocumentReference personRef = mFirestore.collection..................
batch.set(personRef, personData);

// Multiple times
for (Product product : myProductList) { 
    DocumentReference productRef = mFirestore.collection...............
    batch.set(productRef, product, SetOptions.merge());
    operationCounter++;
    if (operationCounter == 500) { 
       batch.commit();
       // Start a new one
       batch = mFirestore.batch();
       // Reset counter
       operationCounter = 0; 
}

// This is just 1 time
DocumentReference inventoryRef = mFirestore.collection..................
batch.set(inventoryRef, inventory);
```

My goal is to be able to generate multiple batches to avoid the mentioned error and to be able to execute them one after another.

Comment: Use a counter variable and increment its value every time you add a write to the batch.  Every time you increment, check if the counter is 500.  When that happens, commit the current batch and start a new one, picking up where you left off.

Comment: @DougStevenson Starting a new one from the `onComplete` method of the batch? The thing is, the `commit` is done in another thread, so, all the code after the `commit` will be executed and I don't know exactly how to wait until the first `commit` is done to continue with the next `commit`. In the examples I have found for Web, they are using `async/task` to do this, but, we don't have that in Android.

Comment: You get a Task where you can attach a callback (as you're showing now).  Use that to continue where you left off.  You will not be able to complete this in a simple loop.

Comment: Will be helpful for you an answer that implies doing an operation when the previous one is completed?

Comment: @AlexMamo Hi, not really. An answer from the previous batch is not needed. If this is what you mean.

Comment: No, not an answer from the previous batch, an answer from the previous "any" operation. My solution will not use a batch.

Comment: @AlexMamo I understand, well, I need to use a batch to guarantee every single data is uploaded together. If your solution works, I can take a look at it, maybe helps, who knows.

Comment: My solution implies doing a new operation once the previous one is completed, not in a batch but in single operations.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it, in the next way:

```
const BATCH_SIZE = 5;

let batch = db.batch();
let j = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  // Do here the stuff you need

  // Add the stuff you have done to the batch
  const ref = db.collection(collection).doc(document);
  batch.set(ref, data);

  // Push the data
  if (j === BATCH_SIZE) {
    await batch.commit();
    batch = db.batch();
    j = 0; // Reset
  } else j++;

}

// Push the remaining data into Firestore
await batch.commit();
```

Keep in mind the remaining data will be less than `BATCH_SIZE` (in this case 5). The constant `BATCH_SIZE` will indicate the size of data inside the batch.